# Ember.js not persisting records with shared templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently building an Ember.js CRUD app and having issues with creating records using a shared template. I'm attempting to use the `edit.hbs` file to also create records.

edit.hbs:

```
<div>
  <label>Server name</label>
  {{input value=name}}

  <label>Operating system</label>
  {{input value=operating_system}}

  <label>Build stage</label>
  {{input value=build_stage}}
</div>
<button {{action 'save'}}> ok </button>
```

serverCreateRoute.js.coffee:

```
Warthog.ServersCreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: ->
    Em.Object.create()

  renderTemplate: ->
    @render('server.edit', controller: 'serversCreate')
```

serverCreateController.js.coffee:

```
Warthog.ServersCreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      var newServer = this.store.createRecord('server', this.get('model'));
      newServer.save();
      this.transitionToRoute('server', newServer);
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the error upon clicking the 'ok' button in the form:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object server has no method '_create'
```

**Update**

Ember.js version: 1.2.0

Ember Data version: 1.0.0-beta.2

**Update**

After playing with multiple combinations of Ember and Ember-data, I am now able to create records; however, newly created records do not persist after refreshing the page. Please note that upon creating a new record, I am redirected to `/#/servers/null` - as expected, the Ember console shows these records' ids as null. Below is the output received after creating a record

`POST http://testdomain.warthog.dev/servers 422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

**Update**

Turns out there was a `validates_presence_of` scope on my rails model. Removing that allows the records to persist, as well as updating Ember Data

Comment: I think this is a bug in an older version of ember data, try to update to use the lastest version http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.3/ember-data.js

Comment: I'm using Ember within a Rails app and have updated the`ember-rails` and `ember-source` gems; unfortunately, the error persists

Comment: Ok, just update your question with the current version of ember and ember-data. I will give a look later. You can see the versions displayed in the console.

Comment: Include the following in your Gemfile. `gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.3'`

Comment: Got it - thanks! I'm now able to save records but they're not persisting after a page refresh. I'm going to troubleshoot this and update with the issues I can't resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in a older version of ember data.
To update your current version of ember data in rails asset pipline use the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ember-data-source', '~> 1.0.0.beta.3'
```